# Three.js - Animation not being displayed on browser

Tags: json, animation, three.js, avatar

I have been trying to display an animation on the browser using three.js and here is the result:
[avatar_jsffidle](https://jsfiddle.net/v6qd358n/15/). The avatar is being displayed but there is no animation. Can someone help me please? Below is the complete code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first Three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="models/three.js"></script>

    <script>

    var camera, light, renderer, objeto, animation, helpset, clock;

    var loader;

    function init() {

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x666666 ) );

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xdfebff, 1.75 );
            light.position.set( 50, 200, 100 );
            light.position.multiplyScalar( 1.3 );

            light.castShadow = true;
            //light.shadowCameraVisible = true;

            light.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
            light.shadowMapHeight = 1024;

            var d = 300;

            light.shadowCameraLeft = -d;
            light.shadowCameraRight = d;
            light.shadowCameraTop = d;
            light.shadowCameraBottom = -d;

            light.shadowCameraFar = 1000;
            light.shadowDarkness = 0.5;

            scene.add( light );


            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


            camera.position.z = 5;

            clock = new THREE.Clock();

            loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();  
            loader.load( 'models/SL-MD-avatar_erica78.json', addModel );

            function addModel( geometry,  materials ){

                    materials[0].skinning = true;
                    materials[0].color = "0xb091cc";

                    var m = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(materials);

                    console.log(materials[0]);
                    objeto= new THREE.SkinnedMesh( geometry, m);
                    scene.add(objeto);

                    objeto.castShadow = true;
                    objeto.receiveShadow = true;

                    scene.add(objeto);
                    helpset = new THREE.SkeletonHelper(objeto);
                    //scene.add(helpset);

                    animation = new THREE.Animation(objeto, geometry.animations[0]);
                    animation.play();


            } 
        }

        function render() {

            delta = 0.75 * clock.getDelta();

            scene.traverse(function(child) {
                if (child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh){  

                    child.rotation.y += .01;
                }
          });

          THREE.AnimationHandler.update( delta );
        }

        function animate(){
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            render();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        init();
        animate(); 


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your fiddle was using r54. [Updated](https://jsfiddle.net/Atrahasis/v6qd358n/13/). the console tells there is a problem in the json, look at it. I cannot indent it and watch it line by line. have you edited it ?

Comment: I have edited my original post with updated link to the jsffidle. I put the JSON file with indentation (in external resources, there is another link with same name). So can you can open it, copy and paste to a .json file and upload it to a server, just like you did with the three.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the json file the arrays `skinIndices` and `skinWeights` only contain 0 values. This means that you have created the bones but not assigned vertices to them. In Blender you should also only see the bones moving but not the body.

Here is a test so you can see there is no problem with the threejs animation code :

- the moving bones are referenced as `"parent":9` and `13` in the json (the shoulders bones).
- replace some 0 values in the `skinIndices` array with 9 and 13 values.
- Refresh your page : those vertices will animate the same way the shoulders do in Blender.

Now you need to read a tutorial about skinning in Blender :)

Comment: please upvote for the 4 hours i spent on it since yesterday ^^

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry about that.

Comment: no pblm i was really intrigued since there was no more errors and the json had all the needed parameters.